# How to run process in background with visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, process, background, hidden

How to run in background this  wifi window.

http://i.hizliresim.com/o3MMP7.png

My Code is dont work and background worker dont work.

```
Private Sub ara()
    RichTextBox1.Clear()

    Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c netsh wlan show networks"
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    p.Start()
    Dim output As String = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    RichTextBox1.Text = output
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ara()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim p1 As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    p1.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe"
    p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "shell:::{38A98528-6CBF-4CA9-8DC0-B1E1D10F7B1B}"
    p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    p1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    p1.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: use a background worker or a Thread also, what errors are you getting? `My code is not work` doesn't cut the mustard.

Comment: it seems that the window.Let me try background worker

Comment: background worker dont work

Comment: i think there is more to this code than you have posted, perhaps you can show a bit more of your code :)

Comment: add more code ı want hide wifi windows

Comment: start the worker from outside the timer and do a while(true) [this is for c# but vb.net shouldnt be too different]

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work

Comment: what does your code work without the background worker? what does it do?

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/ljVQjk.png

ı want the hide this window screen

Comment: Are you still struggling with getting available Wi-Fi SSIDs? If so, maybe check this out, most answers I find use it: http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/

Comment: abi, here is a link that i found that migght help, If you have no luck manking a program to block the wifi panel, why not just remove the icon? .https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252594(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Otherwise if you for some reason don't want/cannot use ManagedWifi, I'd say you'd have to P/Invoke the WinAPI functions on your own: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706749(v=vs.85).aspx